# Place marker on rotated map at lat lon coordinates

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, gps, maps, coordinates

[Graph of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgZF8.png)

So I have lat lon coordinates for the map corners (pink), and I have GPS input from the device telling me where the user is (black dot). I need to place a marker on the user's location. The problem is, that the map isn't oriented as it is in the real world. It is tilted 45-46 degrees. How should I go about calculating the values for the red dots? They should be 0-1 on x and y axis relative to the users location in between the corners of the map.

Using Unity and C#

Answer (score 0):

use `markers.push(marker)` or refer https://developers.google.com/maps/